# Travelling wave is an equilibrium (time independent) solution

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE.
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)-w,~~~~~w_t=\varepsilon(u-\gamma w),~~~~~~~(1)
$$
where $f(u)=u(u-a)(1-u), 0<a<\frac{1}{2}, \varepsilon,\gamma >0, \varepsilon\ll 1,\gamma\ll 1$.

A travelling wave for (1) is a solution that is a function of the single variable $\xi=x-ct$, i.e. $(u(\xi),w(\xi))$ satisfies
$$
-cu'=u''+f(u)-w,~~~~~-cw'=\varepsilon (u-\gamma w),
$$
where $'=d/d\xi$.

Now there is a statement I do not understand.

> > If (1) is recast in a moving coordinate frame, i.e., in terms of variables $\xi=x-ct$ and $t$, it becomes
> >     $$
> > u_t=u_{\xi\xi}+cu_{\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~w_t=cw_{\xi}+\varepsilon(u-\gamma w).~~~~~(2)
> > $$
> >     The travelling wave is an equilibrium (time indepdenent) solution of (2). Moreover, any translate of a travelling wave is also a travelling wave.

I do not see how to get (2) and why the travelling wave is an equilibrium (time independent) solution of (2); moreover, I do not see that a translate is also a travelling wave.

If I want to express (1) in $t$ and $\xi$ instead of $t$ and $x$, then it seems to be that $u_{xx}=u_{\xi\xi}+cu_{\xi}$?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to consider $u$ (and $w$) as a function of $\xi$ and $t$, so $u = u(\xi,t) = u(x-c t,t)$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(\xi,t) = \frac{\partial^2 \xi}{\partial x^2} u_{\xi} + \left(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \right)^2 u_{\xi\xi} = u_{\xi \xi}
\end{equation}
by the chain rule and product rule. Likewise, by the chain rule, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(\xi,t) = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} u_\xi + u_t = -c u_\xi + u_t,
\end{equation}
since $u$ depends on $t$ both directly through its second argument and indirectly through $\xi$.